# Filtering Values Produced by an ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

I am using an ARRAYFORMULA to extract unique values from a list of names and total up a second column for each of those names.

Here is some example data and the ARRAYFORMULA I am using

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN3Xo.png)

[ARRAYFORMULA in cell E3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpkBO.png)

=ARRAYFORMULA({{unique(B3:B11)},{sumif(B3:B11, (unique(B3:B11)),C3:C11)}})

What I would like to do is filter out those names where the total number of tokens is zero - i.e. I would like Peter to be filtered out of the list because he has a net total of zero Tokens.

[I'd also like to have Peter, and any others, displayed in a separate list, but I guess if you can help me crack this first part I can help myself crack the second part]

Is there a way I can achieve what I want with a single ARRAYFORMULA?  Is there another (better) way to achieve the same result?

I've bashed my head against this for a while so would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({B3:C}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col1)''"); 
 "where Col2 is not null"; )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can't quite get it to work, but I'll have a little play round

Comment: Curly Brackets - got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Query and Filter

[image: An image of a two tables, raw input and desired output]

`=FILTER(QUERY(A2:B10,"select A, SUM(B) group by A"),QUERY(A2:B10,"select SUM(B) group by A") > 0)`

You don't need an array formula. The `FILTER` on the outside of the `QUERY` takes care of our zero token problem. And the `QUERY` selects column A and `SUM` of B and returns the proper names and sums, so that there are no repeating names. We need a second identical `QUERY` for the `FILTER` to compare 0s against, Because our `QUERY` doesn't exist outside of the formula. Every reference you make to the `QUERY` requires you to perform the `QUERY` again.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, and thanks also for the explanation - I had an inkling that I needed to make some kind of 'recursive' call to the list created